# Scale images and float them in a row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got a wrapper with a `max-width` of `1400px`. In this `div` are two `img` elements width different sizes. I'd like to float them in a row using flexbox. They should fit in in the 1400px width and still look good, so they have to be scaled like in the picture (red border is the div with 1400px `max-width`). How can I solve this? I hope it's clear enough.

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/hd1080">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/vga">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap image inside `div` and adjust the flex property to make one bigger than the other like this :

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1400px;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.first {
  height:300px;
  flex:2;
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
.second {
  height:300px;
  flex:1;
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

img {
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/hd1080">
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/vga">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible solution yes, but I have to use img elements...so this don't really solve my problem.